# Pass arguments to inner anonymous function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scope, closures

I try to make a function in WordPress to add customizer color settings with JS.
My function is:

```
function customize_color(id,selector,prop){
    wp.customize(id, function(value) {
        value.bind(function(to) {
            $(selector).css({   
                prop:to
            });
        });
    })
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
customize_color('body_background','body','background')
```

With the debugger I notice that inside the `function(to)` I can use the `selector` argument from the outer function. But the `prop` isn't accessible there.
As I know it works with the closures. But the `selector` shouldn't be visible in the inner function.

Could somebody say why is it there?
And maybe how to edit this to have access to the `prop`?

---

#### Edit

Thanks to Tim Vermaelen I understood and remembered the `{prop:to}` will create an object with the `prop` key (not `'background'` property as key).
Also the debugger said **"Error: Variable has been optimized out"** for the `prop` var. 
I removed the `{prop:to}` part and could see this variable in the debugger from the inner function.
So the problem is not because of closures...

I found that the right way to crate object keys from string variables is the next:

```
var rules={}
rules[prop]=to
$(selector).css(rules);
```

And thus I can pass object to the `.css()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I believe is the way you use the `.css()` function.
You can pass a collection of properties and values with an object literal, which is what you did. Or you can pass a single property with a value. Both options require some different syntax.

Try this:

```
$(selector).css(prop, to);
```

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the right idea. So I updated my question with the solution.